# Bootstrap Accordian Column Not Contracting or Expanding

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion

I've searched for the answer on here but I can't find anything that answers my question about why the bootstrap accordion is not expanding. For other users it was the ordering of their JavaScript src link in their header and I've checked but that isn't the issue for me. When I click on the accordion header it does not contract but instead jumps to the body of the text (the text is always expanded).
I want the accordion expansion to be contained within a column on the left side of the layout and for the accordion to be expandable and retractable on a click. I wondered if my JQuery was causing a conflict (I'm using a heightmatch to make the grey column on the right match whatever the column on the left is.) The height match stopped working once I made the column on the left an accordion but I have tried removing the link in the header and it does not appear to have made a difference.
This is what is looks like:
[the layout of the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFT8j.jpg)
This is my code for the layout:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var height = $('#collapseOne').outerHeight();
  $('#profilePanel').css('height', height + 'px');
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#collapseOne {
  background-color: #d5d5d5;
}
.row {
  height: 100%;
}
.h1 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.h3 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.page-header {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.headerone {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3.5em;
  background-color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.panel-footer {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0f0f0f;
}
.container-fluid {
  padding: 0;
}
.main {
  height: 100%;
}
.row {
  height: 100%;
}
.row #gameInfo {
  padding: 0.8em;
  padding-top: 0.1em;
  background-color: #d5d5d5;
}
.row #mainContent {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.row #profilePanel {
  padding: 0.8em;
  background-color: #d5d5d5;
  height: 100%;
}
#profilePanel img {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel='shortcut icon' href='../image/favicon2.png' type='image/png' />
  <title>GameSetMatch</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <link rel="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script src="getheight.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="page-header">
      <div class="headerone">
        <img src="../image/gamesetmatchlogo2.png" alt="logo" width="150" />GameSetMatch</div>
    </div>
    <main>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
          <div id="gameInfo">
            <div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                Collapsible Group Item #1
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                  Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
                  on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
                  raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
          <div id="mainContent">
            <p>Main content will be here at a later point</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
          <div id="profilePanel">
            <img src="../image/profileicon.png" alt="Profile Icon" width="90" />
            <h3>User Name</h3>
            <p>Useremail@gmail.com</p>
            <p>Number of user victories</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <footer class="panel-footer">
      <p>&#169; 2016 Copywright of GameSetMatch</p>
    </footer>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's saying $ is not defined. Jquery not included.

Comment: You've forgotten to load jQuery by the looks of it... Make sure it's referenced prior to BootStrap's JS.

Comment: I updated my header with the jquery link and now the match height is working but unfortunately the accordion is still not working.

Comment: I put the jquery link at the top of the header above everything else too...

Comment: The jquery and bootstrap's js should be at the END of the document. Before the closing body tag. First jquery link, then Bootstrap link.

Comment: Thank you all! It works now! I've still got much to learn but after all this trouble I won't forget the proper position for jQuery and JavaScript links.

Comment: Can you explain which comment helped you so the answer could be moved to the answer section?